# How to instanciate Xilinx differential clock buffer with chisel3 blackboxes?

Tags: scala, xilinx, chisel

I want to write a simple chisel3 blinking led design on my [AC701 kit](https://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/ek-a7-ac701-g.html) (artix7). But to do that I have to instantiate a clock input differential buffer. Xilinx give the following verilog template to do that :

```
IBUFDS #(
    .DIFF_TERM("TRUE"),
    .IOSTANDARD("DEFAULT")
) IBUFDS1_inst (
    .O(clock1), // Clock buffer
    .I(clock1_p), // Diff_p clock
    .IB(clock1_n) // Diff_n clock
);
```

I read on [chisel documentation](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/2.2.0/manual.html) that I have to use «blackbox» class to instantiate it. But I can't do it.
I tried this :

```
class IbufdsParam extends VerilogParameters {
    val DIFF_TERM  = "TRUE" 
    val IOSTANDARD = "DEFAULT"
}

class IBUFDS extends BlackBox {
  val params = new IbufdsParam()
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val O = Output(Bool())
    val I = Input(Bool())
    val IB = Input(Bool())})
  io.O.setName("O")
  io.I.setName("I")
  io.IB.setName("IB")

  /* For simulation */
  io.O := io.I & ~io.IB
}
```

But it seem that chisel3 doesn't know VerilogParameters class :

```
[error] blinking_led/blink.scala:5: not found: type VerilogParameters
[error] class IbufdsParam extends VerilogParameters {
```

And I don't know how to say «do not use clock and reset with this module».

Once this blackbox correctly declared, I will have to connect the output clock ('O') to the main clock of my blinking module. I'm not sure about how to do that. I'm thinking about that :

```
class Blink extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val clock_p = Input(Bool())
    val clock_n = Input(Bool())
    val led  = Output(Bool())
  })

  val ibufds = IBUFDS()

  Driver.implicitClock := ibufds.io.O
  ibufds.io.I := io.clock_p
  ibufds.io.IB:= io.clock_n

...
}
```

But I think it's maybe not the right way, isn't it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a documentation failure, I'll be sure to add a page on the [chisel3 wiki](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel3/wiki) for parameterized blackboxes shortly. Parameterized blackboxes are currently any experimental feature of Chisel3 that can be used by passing a Map of String to Strings or Ints or Longs to the BlackBox constructor. Thus for your particular case, try:

```
import chisel3._
import chisel3.experimental._

class IBUFDS extends BlackBox(Map("DIFF_TERM" -> "TRUE",
                                  "IOSTANDARD" -> "DEFAULT")) {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val O = Output(Clock())
    val I = Input(Clock())
    val IB = Input(Clock())
  })
}
```

In chisel3, there is no implicit clock or reset for BlackBoxes, ports also can't be renamed but will instead get the name given in the io Bundle (without any io_ added). Simulation behavior is also not currently supported, but you can provide a Verilog implementation and simulate your whole design with Verilator.

Now, we want to use the `O` output of `IBUFDS` and connect it to some `Blink` Module. You cannot use a submodule to overrule the clock of its parent, but you can set the clock of a submodule. Thus, I can provide some `Top` Module that instantiates both `IBUFDS` and `Blink`, eg.

```
class Blink extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val led = Output(Bool())
  })
  val reg = Reg(init = false.B)
  reg := !reg
  io.led := reg
}

class Top extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val clock_p = Input(Clock())
    val clock_n = Input(Clock())
    val led  = Output(Bool())
  })

  val ibufds = Module(new IBUFDS)
  ibufds.io.I := io.clock_p
  ibufds.io.IB:= io.clock_n

  val blink = Module(new Blink)
  blink.clock := ibufds.io.O
  io.led := blink.io.led   
}
```

This code leads to `IBUFDS` being instantiated as follows:

```
IBUFDS #(.DIFF_TERM("TRUE"), .IOSTANDARD("DEFAULT")) ibufds (
  .IB(ibufds_IB),
  .I(ibufds_I),
  .O(ibufds_O)
);
```

which I believe should do what you want!

Comment: Thanks for this complet response. You says we can provide Verilog implementation of the blackbox for verilator simulation. Is it possible to provide it in the same file ? Can you say how to do it ?

Comment: No problem! The Verilog must be located in a separate file that you include in the latter part of your build process (ie. *after* Chisel+Firrtl has generated its Verilog). Essentially, on the Verilog simulation step, you just need to be sure to include the Verilog file with the blackboxes implementations along with the Chisel-generated Verilog.