# How to delete clock signal on chisel3 top module?

Tags: verilog, xilinx, chisel

I have a blinking led design who use a differential clock input (xilinx AC701 kit).
To instantiate the Xilinx differential buffer I'm using a BlackBox as explained by jkoening [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41241017/how-to-instanciate-xilinx-differential-clock-buffer-with-chisel3-blackboxes/41251233#41251233):

```
class Top extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle{
    val clock_p = Input(Clock())
    val clock_n = Input(Clock())
    val led = Output(Bool())
  })

  val ibufds = Module(new IBUFDS)
  ibufds.io.I := io.clock_p
  ibufds.io.IB:= io.clock_n

  val blink = Module(new Blink)
  blink.clock := ibufds.io.O
  io.led := blink.io.led  

}
```

That works, but On the Top verilog module I have a useless clock input :

```
module Top(
  input   clock,
  input   reset,
  input   io_clock_p,
  input   io_clock_n,
  output  io_led
);
...
```

Then on the target only `io_clock_p` and `io_clock_n` are used for clock input. `clock` signal is useless. Is there a proper way to hide it ?

Comment: Why aren't you asking the same about `reset`? I'm guessing `clock` and `reset` are hard-coded to always exist, because they are so fundamental.

Comment: In fact, I'm asking the same about reset. clock and reset not always exist, they aren't exist in blackbox for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After [discussion](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel3/pull/469) with Chisel3 team a feature has been added to support this.

The solution is to use a RawModule:

```
class Top extends RawModule {
  val clock_p = IO(Input(Clock()))
  val clock_n = IO(Input(Clock()))
  val led = IO(Output(Bool()))

  val ibufds = Module(new IBUFDS)
  ibufds.io.I := clock_p
  ibufds.io.IB:= clock_n

  withClockAndReset(ibufds.io.O, false.B) {
    val blink = Module(new Blink)
    led := blink.io.led
  }
}
```

A raw module has no implicit signal, and name are reflected «has it» in verilog generated file, no «io_» in prefix.

The source code of full blinking led project is available on [this github project](https://github.com/Martoni/blp/blob/master/platforms/kintex7/chisel3/blink.scala) (blinking led project : blp).

[Here](http://www.fabienm.eu/flf/les-blackbox-et-rawmodule-de-chisel3/) is a french description of how to do it. To use this feature, last git master version of chisel3 must be used.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way delete or even rename `clock` and `reset` on Chisel Modules. They are always there. Since Chisel uses positive-edge clocks, you could consider removing `io_clock_p` and using `clock` instead.

This is an oft-requested feature so it may be added in the future, but it is not currently supported.

Comment: Maybe a special module class should be added for 'Top' module as for blackbox.